# Gridview HyperlinkField field visibility determined by another corresponding columns contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, eval

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem, I have spent a considerable amount of time trying alternative solutions to no avail. Any help or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

**The Task**

I need to make my hyperlink field in an asp.net Gridview only visible/clickable if the security column is set to restricted.

**Current output**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6N79.jpg

**The Code**

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ReportID, Reference_Num, Title, Description"
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ReportRequest.aspx?ID={0}&Title={2}&Description={3}"
Text="Request Access" Visible='<%#Eval("Security").ToString()=="Unrestricted"?False:True %>' />
```

So as you can see I'm trying to use the Visible properties of the HyperlinkField with an Eval to read the corresponsing text within the security column.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to a TemplateField with a HyperLink Control and set the visibility there.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ticket Number">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Security").ToString() == "Security" ? false : true %>'>Request Access</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or use the RowDataBound event to locate the generated HyperLink in the correct cell and set the visibility from code behind.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //locate the hyperlink in the correct cell nummer. It is always the first control in the cell
        HyperLink hl = e.Row.Cells[colIndex].Controls[0] as HyperLink;

        //validate the value
        if (row["Security"].ToString() == "Security")
        {
            hl.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the hyperlink control has a similar property to DataNavigateUrlFields? I need to pass the row variables adjacent to the hyperlink to another page

Comment: No, but you can use the same method as the Visible property: `NavigateUrl='<%# "/ReportRequest.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ReportID").ToString() + "&Title=" ... %>'`